# Continuous maps from $\Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

Which of the following statements is true ?

1. There are at most countably many continuous maps from $\Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R$
2. There are at most finitely many continuous surjective maps from $\Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R$
3. There are infinitely many continuous injective maps from $\Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R$
4. There are no continuous bijective maps from $\Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R$

My Attempt:

If I take a function from $\Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R$ that maps Circle to Line such that $f(x,y) = \alpha x$ which is continuous where $\alpha \neq 0$ and $\alpha \in \Bbb R$ but cardinality of $\Bbb R$ is $C$ which is uncountable.  So first two options are discarded. Am I right? If not, correct me with good explanation. Also cardinality of $\Bbb R^2 = C^2$ > $C$ = cardinality of $\Bbb R$ . So there does not exist injective map from $\Bbb R^2$  $\to$  $\Bbb R$ Hence option 3 is not true and 4 is only option that is true. Please help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: Surjective, not subjective.

Comment: Oh, Yes I will correct it.

Comment: $f(x,y) = \alpha x$ does map a circle to a line, it maps the entire plane, $\mathbb R^2$ to the real number line $\mathbb R$.

Comment: $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$ have the same cardinality...

Comment: @Squared , Thanks for point out my mistake about cardinality.

Answer (score 4):

1, 2. I think you're on the right track here, but what is this circle to line business?

3, 4: A continuous injective map from $\mathbb R^2$ to $\mathbb R$ would take each vertical line in $\mathbb R^2$ to an interval in $\mathbb R$ of positive length. How many pairwise disjoint intervals can there be in $\mathbb R?$

Comment: I could not understand what you say ?

Comment: A vertical line, say $\{(0,y)|y\in \mathbb R\}$ or $\{(1,y)|y\in \mathbb R\}$ because the function is continuous must map to a line or line segment.  And because it is injective the line segments mapped to must be disjoint.  Now you have one of these lines $\{(w_0,x)|x\in \mathbb R\}$ for every $w_0\in \mathbb R$ and every one of these lines maps to a line or segment and so we have infinitely many disjoint line segments covering $\mathbb R$.  Is that possible.

Comment: @fleablood: In this argument (especially for option 3) we don't know that the intervals _cover_ $\mathbb R$. The point is rather that there are uncountably many of them.

Comment: I was hinting at that.  But you are right.  I was thinking of the bijection.  But the contradiction I was hinting at was that uncountably many of them can't "fit".

Answer (score 2):

For option 1, Take $f(x,y) = c $  $(c \in \Bbb R)$, is a constant function which is continuous from $\Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R$.But $\Bbb R$ is uncountable. So there exist uncountable many constant continuous functions from $\Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R$. Hence option 1 is not true.

For option 2, Take $f(x , y) = \alpha x$  $(\alpha \in \Bbb R)$, which is a polynomial and polynomial is continuous function from $\Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R$. For all $x \in \Bbb R$ there exist $(x , y)$ in $\Bbb R^2$ such that $f(x , y) = \alpha x$. So $f$ is onto. But choice of such $\alpha$ is uncountable. Hence option 2 is not true.

For option 3, Assume that $f$ is continuous and injective. We know that image of connected set is connected set under continuous map. So $f(\Bbb R^2) = Interval$. If we remove some points from the plane $\Bbb R^2 $ then it is still path connected $\implies$ connected but when we remove point from $\Bbb R$ then it is disconnected. Hence option 3 is not true.

For option 4, Bijective map means a map that is injective as well as surjective. But from 3, it is not injective. So it is not bijective . Hence option 4 is true.